# Beautifulsoup, grab text with link

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i'm making a web spider to automate some of my work.
I have a table with lots of drivers and different version for different operating systems.
So far everything works fine but i'm having a hard time separating the links for each operating system.
I'll post part of the html here, but i can't post the whole page.
The problem is i don't know can i grab each link and the text that's next to it, i can grab all of them but then i don't know what links if for what operating system.

This is the content of one cell in the table, all i need is to get the link along with the OS verstion (win8.1, win10, win7)

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-line-height-alt:9.3pt"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">SfP/StP
    <a href="LINK_TO_FILE">AHWFW0609P_WinB</a>.zip
    </span><span class="MsoHyperlink"><b><sup><span style="font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#984806;background:white;text-decoration:
    none;text-underline:none">Win8.1</span></sup></b></span><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-line-height-alt:9.3pt"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">SfP/StP
    <a href="LINK_TO_FILE">AHWFW0553P_WinT</a></span><span style="color:#1F497D">.</span><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
    &quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">zip</span><span class="MsoHyperlink"><b><sup><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#984806;
    background:white;text-decoration:none;text-underline:none"> Win10</span></sup></b></span><span class="MsoHyperlink"><b><sup><span style="color:#984806;background:white;
    text-decoration:none;text-underline:none"><o:p></o:p></span></sup></b></span></p>
```

here is the code i use to grab the names and the links.

```
file = open(r"Path to HTML file", 'rb')
drivers = {}
rng_lst = [str(x) for x in range(5, 43)]

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(file)

table = soup.findAll('table')[0]
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    if len(cells) > 4:
        cell_num = cells[1].get_text(strip=True)
        if any(cell_num == n for n in rng_lst):
            drv_name = cells[2].get_text(strip=True)
            drivers[drv_name] = {'links': []}
            links = cells[4].findAll('a')
            for link in links:
                drivers[drv_name]['links'].append(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Do you want the text right next to `LINK_TO_FILE`?

Comment: yes, on the web page it looks like this:
link to file.zip Win8.1

link to file.zip Win10

so i need the WinXX right next to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `string` contains the html content

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(string)

for pTag in soup.find_all('p'):
        anchorTag =  pTag.findNext('a')
        linkText =  pTag.find('span', {'class' : 'MsoHyperlink' } ).span.text
        print "LpTag.findNext('a')ink : ", anchorTag["href"]
        print "Text to Link ", linkText
        print
```

would give you an output

```
Link :  LINK_TO_FILE
Text to Link  Win8.1

Link :  LINK_TO_FILE
Text to Link   Win10
```

**What it does?**

By looking at the input string we can know that the anchors and text that we are interested in are present within the `p` tags.

And that the text comes within a `span` tag which inturn comes under another `span` tag which occurs next to the anchor tag.

---

- `soup.find_all('p')` The [find_all](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) will return the list of `p` tags.
- `pTag.findNext('a')` For each of the `p` tag, the [findNext](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) will find the next occurence of the anchor tag. This anchor tag contains the relevant link
- `pTag.find('span', {'class' : 'MsoHyperlink' } )` The [find](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) will find the `span` within the current `p` tag with the attribute `class` set as `MsoHyperlink`

  - `.span` returns the span within the span returned bye `find`
  - `.text` returns the text of the corresponding span

Comment: This looks like it could work, i'm tried it out but sometimes the linkText is a "NoneType" class, and then i can't do anything with it, i assume this happens when the link has no OS version next to it (some drivers are OS independent).
is there any way i can bypass that? i tried comparing " type() == 'bs4.element.Tag' " but that didn't help either

Comment: I suspects you need to have conditional statements to make sure that the html structure is maintained all through out the input string. Or you can employ `try` statements to handle cases where you dont have OS version down the tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
 os_cell = cells[4]
 os_span = os_cell.find("span", class_="MsoHyperlink")
 os = os_span.string
```